# Sorting a class inheriting from a Python list

Tags: python, list, inheritance, overriding

Given the following implementation:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, arg=None):
        super(MyList, self).__init__(arg)

myList = MyList([1,3,2])

print type(myList) # print <class '__main__.MyList'>
print type(sorted(myList)) # print <type 'list'>
```

Is there any method of list() I can override such that `sorted()` will return an instance of `MyList()`?

Comment: Because you called `super(MyList, self).__init__()` with no arguments, your list object is actually entirely empty.

Comment: Right, just corrected

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not; `sorted()` always returns a list whatever iterable you pass into it. This is not limited to your custom class.

`sorted()` takes any iterable, including generators, and outputs a sorted list:

```
>>> sorted((1, 4, 2))
[1, 2, 4]
>>> sorted(xrange(4, -1, -1))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Your class will have a custom `.sort()` method, so in-place sorting should still work:

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...     def __init__(self, arg=None):
...         super(MyList, self).__init__(arg)
...     pass
... 
>>> myList = MyList([1,3,2])
>>> myList.sort()
>>> myList
[1, 2, 3]
>>> type(myList)
<class '__main__.MyList'>
```